# React CRA proxy issue

Tags: reactjs, proxy, fetch, create-react-app

I put the line 'proxy': 'http://192.168.1.36:4000' which corresponds to the IP address and the port of my expressjs API but when I perform a fetch to retrieve information on my server I get an error like:> POST http: // localhost: 3000 / api / users / login 400 (Bad Request). From what I understood from the error, the fetch uses the port of my react app and not that of my express API. Port 3000 is not my API's.

```js
{
  "name": "portfolio",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://192.168.1.36:4000", // This line
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
```

```js
fetch('/api/users/login', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
        })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
            if(!res.error) {
                localStorage.setItem('auth', res.token);
                dispatch({ type: LOGIN, user: res.user, token: res.token });
            } else {
                dispatch({ type: ERROR, message: res.error });
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it using React CRA:

1. Remove `http://localhost:3000` from your REST API POST call, meaning you should just call `POST /api/users/login`
2. Add oneliner proxy in `package.json`: `{ ..., "proxy": "http://localhost:4000/"}`

This should be enough, no need to use in-browser CORS extensions with proxy.